# Download pathName in WebdriverIO

Tags: javascript, testing, path, download, webdriver-io

I am trying to code an specific pathName download for Chrome to test download a file in a specific folder, nevertheless when I put the download route that I want, this one goes to default on chrome and all downloads go to my test file.
Does anyone have an idea to set a download path for testing only?

I tried to use the beforeTest and afterTest functions in conf.js to reset but nothing worked that always keep the first downloadPath